# jQuery: Hook for inserting ajax stuff? Listener?

Tags: jquery, ajax, hook

I'm working on the frontend of a webapplication that does a lot of ajax stuff (e.g. loading comments etc.) … all ajax stuff is done via jQuery functions.

I wonder if there is any way that I can listen for those inserting events? Whenever some ajax request on my site is fired (and completed) I want to call a function. Is there some hook or something I can use to achieve this? Rather that applying the same function call to all already existing ajax functions in my code?

thanks for your help/advise.

Comment: Look at jQuery's global ajax handlers, specifically $.ajaxStop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your AJAX requests to use defaults you set like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function(){} // Do something
});
```

This is called after the `success` function I imagine you're using to insert your elements, and applies to every AJAX request made after.